Manejo de errores en el procedimiento Oracle EBS R12 PL/SQL: ORA-29283 - Operación de archivo no válida: archivo o ruta inexistentes [29434]
He creado 2 programas simultáneos: uno responsable de generar resultados PDF utilizando el ejecutable XDODTEXE, una plantilla RTF y una definición de datos XML. El otro ejecuta el primer programa concurrente, luego copia el archivo PDF del directorio APPLOUT al directorio PEDIDOS. Finalmente, debería enviar un correo electrónico.
Este es mi prc:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REPORTS_DETAILS(
    ERRBUF                  OUT VARCHAR2,
    RETCODE                 OUT VARCHAR2,
    P_ORG_ID                IN NUMBER,
    P_USER_ID               IN NUMBER,
    P_RESP_ID               IN NUMBER,
    P_RESP_APPL_ID          IN NUMBER
) AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS
--
    v_request_id            NUMBER;
    v_layout                BOOLEAN;
    l_phase                 VARCHAR2(100);
    l_status                VARCHAR2(100);
    l_dev_phase             VARCHAR2(100);
    l_dev_status            VARCHAR2(100);
    l_messase               VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_smts                  VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_wait_for_request      BOOLEAN;
    v_newfile               VARCHAR2(100);
    v_oldfile               VARCHAR2(100);
    vfecha1                 VARCHAR2(50) := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
    P_html                  VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_correos               VARCHAR2(32767);
    p_text                  VARCHAR2(1000);
    p_subjects              VARCHAR2(2000);
    p_to                    VARCHAR2(2000) := 'micorreo@micorreo.com'; -- Cambia el correo aquí
    l_error                 VARCHAR2(32767) := NULL;
    v_numero_linea          VARCHAR2(50);
--

CURSOR cEmails IS
    SELECT 'micorreo@micorreo.com' email
    FROM DUAL;

BEGIN
    -- Configuración de NLS
    l_smts := 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE= ''' || 'AMERICAN' || ''' NLS_TERRITORY= ''' || 'AMERICA' || ''' NLS_CURRENCY= ''' || '$' || '''' ||
              ' NLS_ISO_CURRENCY= ''' || 'AMERICA' || ''' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= ''' || '.,' || '''' ||
              ' NLS_CALENDAR= ''' || 'GREGORIAN' || ''' NLS_DATE_FORMAT= ''' || 'DD-MON-RR' || '''' ||
              ' NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE= ''' || 'AMERICAN' || ''' NLS_SORT= ''' || 'BINARY' || '''';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_smts;

    -- Inicialización de variables EBS
    mo_global.init('AR'); 
    fnd_global.apps_initialize(user_id      => P_USER_ID,
                               resp_id      => P_RESP_ID,
                               resp_appl_id => P_RESP_APPL_ID);

    mo_global.set_policy_context('S', P_ORG_ID);
    dbms_application_info.set_client_info(P_ORG_ID);
    apps.fnd_profile.put('ORG_ID', P_ORG_ID);

    -- Reporte XML Publisher
    v_layout := FND_REQUEST.ADD_LAYOUT(template_appl_name => '',
                                       template_code      => '',
                                       template_language  => '',
                                       template_territory => '',
                                       output_format      => 'PDF');

    IF v_layout THEN
        v_request_id := apps.FND_REQUEST.SUBMIT_REQUEST
        (application     => '',
         program         => '',
         start_time      => NULL,
         sub_request     => FALSE,
         argument1       => p_org_id,
         argument2       => NULL,
         argument3       => NULL,
         argument4       => NULL,
         argument5       => NULL,
         argument6       => p_id_cliente,
         argument7       => '2024/02/01 00:00:00',
         argument8       => '2024/02/01 00:00:00'
        );

        COMMIT;

        IF v_request_id <> 0 THEN
            l_wait_for_request := apps.fnd_concurrent.wait_for_request(request_id => v_request_id,
                                                                       interval   => 20,
                                                                       max_wait   => 0,
                                                                       phase      => l_phase,
                                                                       status     => l_status,
                                                                       dev_phase  => l_dev_phase,
                                                                       dev_status => l_dev_status,
                                                                       message    => l_messase);

            COMMIT;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.output, '== CREACIÓN DEL ARCHIVO EN APPLOUT ==');

    -- Envío de reporte por correo
    fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.output, '== MOVER ARCHIVOS A CARPETAS ==');

    v_newfile := 'Report___Detalle_de_Movim_' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DDMONYYYY') || '.pdf';
    v_oldfile := 'XXReport___Detalle_de_Movim_' || v_request_id || '_1.pdf';

    BEGIN
        UTL_FILE.FCOPY ('APPLOUT', v_oldfile, 'PEDIDOS', v_newfile); 
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN UTL_FILE.invalid_path THEN
            fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'Invalid Path al Crear Archivo. '||v_newfile||' Error invalid_path: '|| SQLERRM);
        WHEN UTL_FILE.invalid_mode THEN
            fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'Invalid Mode al Crear Archivo. '||v_newfile||' Error invalid_mode: '|| SQLERRM);
        WHEN UTL_FILE.invalid_operation THEN
            fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'Invalid Operation al Crear Archivo. '||v_newfile||' Error invalid_operation: '|| SQLERRM);
        WHEN UTL_FILE.invalid_filehandle THEN
            fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'Invalid Filehandle al Crear Archivo. '||v_newfile||' Error invalid_filehandle: '|| SQLERRM);
        WHEN UTL_FILE.read_error THEN
            fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'Invalid Read al Crear Archivo. '||v_newfile||' Error read_error: '|| SQLERRM);
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'Exception no controlada al Crear Archivo. '||v_newfile||'- Error Others : ' || SQLERRM);
    END;

    FOR c IN cEmails LOOP
        BEGIN
            IF l_correos IS NULL THEN
                l_correos := 'micorreo@micorreo.com';
            ELSE
                l_correos := l_correos || ';' || c.email;
            END IF;
        END;
    END LOOP;

    fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.output,'== ENVIO DE CORREOS ==');
    -- EMAIL
    p_text := 'Detalle de movimientos ' || vfecha1;
    p_subjects := 'Detalle de movimientos ' || vfecha1;

    P_html := '<html><head></head><body> Saludos Cordiales,<br>' || CHR (13);
    P_html := P_html || '<p>Se Adjunta Detalle de movimientos al  '|| vfecha1|| '</p>'|| CHR (13);
    P_html := P_html || '<br></br>' || CHR (13);
    l_correos := NULL;

    fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.output,'== COMIENZA ITERACION ==');

    P_html := P_html || '<br><br><br>Atentamente,<br><br><br><br><b><i>Este correo es generado automaticamente, favor no responder.</i></b> </body></html>' || CHR (13);
    P_html := P_html || ' ';

    BEGIN
        pits_send_mail.send_email (p_directory     => 'PEDIDOS'
                                   p_sender        => p_to,
                                   p_recipient     => 'micorreo@micorreo.com',
                                   p_cc            => NULL,
                                   p_bcc           => NULL,
                                   p_subject       => p_subjects,
                                   p_body          => P_html,
                                   p_attachment1   => v_newfile,
                                   p_attachment2   => NULL,
                                   p_attachment3   => NULL,
                                   p_attachment4   => NULL,
                                   p_error         => l_error);

        apps.fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.LOG, 'l_error - ' || l_error);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            Fnd_file.Put_line(Fnd_file.LOG,'Exception no controlada Email - ' || SQLERRM);
    END;

    COMMIT;

    P_html := NULL;

    apps.fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG,'===================================================================================');
END REPORTS_DETAILS;

Cómo obtener los parámetros de FND_REQUEST.ADD_LAYOUT?
¿Cómo obtener mo_global.init?
¿Hay una consulta? Porque para obtener esos datos, dependo de la pantalla de mi primer concurrente que genera la salida PDF.
¿Cómo obtener FND_REQUEST.ADD_LAYOUT?
FND_REQUEST.SUBMIT_REQUEST Genera la salida PDF, el problema radica en copiar el archivo y enviarlo como un adjunto.
He validado el nombre del archivo en el directorio APPLOUT y es correcto, y los directorios de origen y destino existen en Oracle.
He validado los permisos de mi usuario y tiene permisos activos de ejecución, lectura y escritura.
He realizado pruebas cambiando los datos de mi procedimiento almacenado con los datos de otros procedimientos concurrentes y la salida es exitosa. Entonces, el problema radica en cómo se obtienen los parámetros de FND_REQUEST.ADD_LAYOUT, mo_global.init.

¿Agregaste el concurrente y la plantilla? ¿Con cuáles parámetros?
